# optimization of code on smartpy

Tags: gas

what are the codes that costs more gas in a operations and what are the features that should be used less inside smart contract to avoid gas exceeds? Like is it costly to use local variable or calling onchain view of another contract ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some orders of magnitude:

- cryptography operations can cost up to thousands of gas units with huge cost differences between the supported curves (checking a tz2 signature is 50 gas units, checking a tz4 one is 1600 gas units).
- serialization and type checking cost about 0.1 gas units times the size of your Micheline tree.
- Reading from disk costs 200 gas units + 2 gas units per read kilobytes, writing to disk costs 200 gas units + 4 gas units per written kilobyte.
- Everything else is cheap unless you manipulate large data.

Also, when investigating gas waste, note that you can get a detailed gas consumption report with the `--trace-stack` option of `octez-client run script`. This will tell you, for each step of the interpretation of your script, how much gas the step consumes.